# how to get typing the last character of a string to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running an experiment on text entry where currently, clicking a button will activate a new trial. I want the new trial to activate without using a button (i.e. to automatically appear when the user enters the last character of the target phrase). Here is the code I have so far:

```
saveData = () => {

    let log_file = JSON.stringify({
        targetPhrase: this.state.targetPhrase,
        inputPhrase: this.state.inputPhrase,
        timeElapsed: (new Date().getTime() - timeStart)/1000,

    })
    download(log_file, "results.txt", "text/plain");
    timer=0;
    this.type='normal';
    state +=1;
    if((state>2 && state <7) || (state>10 && state <15)){
        this.type='zoom';
    }

};

onClick = () =>{

  this.saveData();
  this.setState({
        targetPhrase : getTargetPhrase(),
        inputPhrase: "",
        inputChar: "",

  });
};
onInput = () =>{return this.state.inputPhrase;};

render(){
```

Comment: I think you should bind to onKeyUp event of the input box, then you should check the value of the input, if it's the same as the string you're asking him to type, you can call whatever method you need.

Comment: I don't think **saveData()** function has anything to do with the question. Who calls onInput? Is it called on each character input or you manually call it at some point?